# conda env build fails with "[Errno 28] No space left on device"

Tags: conda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a new conda environment in our Sagemaker ec2 environment in a terminal session.  Packages in the original copy of the environment were corrupted, and the environment became unusable. The issue couldn't be fixed by removing packages and re-installing or using `conda update`.

I nuked the environment with `conda env remove -n python3-cn` and then attempted to recreate the environment with:

```
conda env create -p /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/anaconda3/envs/python3-cn --file=${HOME}/SageMaker/efs/.sagemaker/python3-cn_environment.yml --force
```

This environment has been created a number of times in several ec2 instances for individual Sagemaker users.

Conda logs the following:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages
pytest-arraydiff-0.2 | 14 KB     | ##################################################################################################### | 100% 
partd-0.3.8          | 32 KB     | ##################################################################################################### | 100% 

... several progress bar lines later...

psycopg2-2.7.5       | 507 KB    | ##################################################################################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::mkl-2018.0.3-1'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 28] No space left on device
()
```

The `No space left on device` error is consistent. I've tried

- `conda clean --all`, removing the environment, re-building the environment
- removing the caches, removing the environment, re-building the environment
- removing the environment, shutting down and restarting JuypiterLab (our Sagemaker is configured to create `python3-cn` if the environment doesn't exist when JupyterLab starts)

In the first two, I get `Errno 28`.

In the last one, the instance is not created, `conda env list` does not show the `python3-cn`, but I see there is a `python3-cn` directory in the `anaconda/envs/` directory. If I do `conda activate python3-cn`, I see the prompt change, but the environment is unusuable. If I try `conda update --all`, I get a notification that one of the package files has been corrupted.

Not really sure what to do here. I'm looking for space hogs, but not really finding anything significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the ebs volume amount of your notebook ... this blog explains it well: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-your-notebook-volume-size-up-to-16-tb-with-amazon-sagemaker/

Also, best practice is to use lifecycle configuration scripts to build/add new dependencies ... official docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html

This github page has some great template examples ... for example setting up specific configs like conda, etc: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts

Answer (score 0):

@thePurplePython Thank you for this info-- it's most helpful. I found that there were some hidden directories in the notebook that were consuming JUST ENOUGH space to allow the build to start, but not to finish. However, I really like the lifecycle config and will look at it as our dependencies grow, which is bound to happen.